# Is GData Youtube API's Search Videos method free(Quota free)?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, gdata, gdata-api

This is the link for retrieving list of videos related to a keyword:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=SEARCH_TERM

We can successfully get an xml response even when we do not provide an API key. As such google says you to provide the developer key like this:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=SEARCH_TERM&key=DEVELOPER_KEY

So what should I infer from this behavior? Is the list video method free of any Quota (ie Can I make unlimited calls from any IP at any rate?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is limited per IP basis, which is less than API quota. Best practice is to use developer key to have better quota limits.

Comment: Are you sure about this ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise anyone could've spammed with these requests right?